# Get nonroot UID/GID from Java8 distroless image

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, java-8, terraform, dockerfile

I want to run the container under a `nonroot` user (username already exists) from Java image: [gcr.io/distroless/java:8](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless/GLOBAL/java@sha256:34c3598d83f0dba27820323044ebe79e63ad4f137b405676da75a3905a408adf/details?tag=8). This user is already present in the image and I've added a command to the Dockerfile: `USER nonroot`

Now I want to add it to the K8s manifest file, which requires UID/GID only (not literal username):

```
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: <USER_ID>
    runAsGroup: <GROUP_ID>
    runAsNonRoot: true
```

So, the question is how to get `nonroot` user's ID and group's ID from the distroless image (no shell inside)?

If I don't add anything to the manifest file, the container starts with user `nonroot` (seen in logs). Does it mean that that root isn't used anymore (and is enough for the container's security)?

UPDATE:

Adding only `run_as_non_root = true` to the Kubernetes' deployment  manifest file works fine, but in Terraform configuration file there is already present `fs_group = 1234`, which also automatically adds:

```
run_as_group = 0
run_as_user  = 0
```

It makes the pod to fails with the error `Error: container's runAsUser breaks non-root policy`.
Setting nonroot's ID/GID would fix this problem, but how can I get these values ID from the distroless java image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't add anything to the Kubernetes manifest, then the container will run as the `USER` declared in the Dockerfile.  Unless you specifically need to force the container to run as some other user ID, this is probably fine.

```yaml
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  # but don't usually need to specific specific uid/gid
```

A well-designed image will also be able to tolerate running as an arbitrary user.  If it doesn't write files at all, or only writes into world-writable directories like `/tmp` and to storage directories it specifically expects to have mounted from outside the container, then it doesn't really matter if the numeric user ID "exists" inside the container at all, and you can choose any user ID you want here.

```yaml
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 9876  # or anything else that's not 0
  runAsGroup: 9876
```

Comment: Thanks, David Maze for the help. It works in Kubernetes .yaml file. But in terraform configuration file when the security_context is used, `run_as_group = 0, run_as_user = 0` is added automatically, and the pod fails with the error: `container's runAsUser breaks non-root policy`.

Comment: The question I answered had no mention of Terraform or of overrides that might automatically set the container back to running as root.  Can you please roll back the question to the original form?

Comment: Sorry @DavidMaze for confusing you. You are absolutely right, and I've rolled back the question. Additional information was added in the UPDATE section to the question so that this would be more clear.